# JQuery slide toggle weird behavior with box-shadow

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have slide toggle animation effect for a toast message, toast message have box-shadow in CSS, but whenever the toggle happens box-shadow looks weird and back to normal when the slide completes

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert-toaster" style="display: none;">Add to Playlist</div>
<button id="toggle">
Toggle
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.alert-toaster {
    width:150px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    right:2%;
    background-color: #C9234C;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) !important;
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function(){
   $(".alert-toaster").show("slide", {direction:"right"}, 500 );
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".alert-toaster").hide("slide", {direction:"right"}, 500 );
                    },2000);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mrwsgs58/1/)

It looks very weird to me, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add *margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;* to create enough space for your label.

```
.alert-toaster {
    width:150px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    right:2%;
    background-color: #C9234C;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;   
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) !important;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrwsgs58/3/

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it with a small css rule.

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

JQuery wraps your element with a div to which it applies an `overflow: hidden` during the animation.

Maybe you can find an option to avoid that.

EDIT:
It might not be the **best** solution though. You'll have some bad side effects with this.

Try to add a wrapper yourself, to which you add the drop-shadow. Still animate the inside div.

Here's a solution https://jsfiddle.net/xfn1j9hs/ without using jquery for the animation, but CSS only.